# Async task or Service which one is faster to get data form server using httpclient in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Async Task or Normal thread which one is best for network operation for fast performance in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572911/async-task-or-normal-thread-which-one-is-best-for-network-operation-for-fast-per)

i am doing a network operation in my activity to get some data from server  using AsyncTask. if i use loacl server i am getting data fast and working fine, when i am using production server which is https connection the process is too late to get data from server.please guide me if i need to use android service rather than Async task.but in emulator there is no difference in speed with local and production server.

Comment: i don't think this has anything to do with `AsyncTask` or `Service`. I am pretty sure it is either your connection which is slow... either the server responds slow..

Comment: Dear Ovidiu Latcu i am using Asynctask for data.When using local server i am getting data fast but using production server its taking too much time.i don't know where is the mistake

Comment: this is what i am telling you. the problem does not reside on your `AsyncTask` code. it is a server problem, or internet speed problem.

Answer (score 2):

In a real situation, loading data can be slow, and network can even be completely unavailable. Writing a good mobile app means making this less obvious to the user. I recommend this talk as a good starting point to learn more: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html